# Autofill multiple cells while filling one cell in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

The excel data looks like below:

- Column A: Name
- Column B: Role
- Column C: Activity
- Column D: Comments

Now in Columns A to C the entries are same and in Column D it is always different. Its like a timesheet of an employee.

So instead of filling Columns A to C the same, I want to put a formula such that when another entry in Column D is made, then Columns A to C are auto populated from the above filled data.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two tables using **Format as Table**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question right, you want to auto populate 2 different cells if a 3rd one is not empty.

> Column A: Name
>   Column B: Role
>   Column C: Activity
>   Column D: Comments
>   Now in Columns A to C the entries are same and in Column D it is always different. Its like a timesheet of an employee.

Now in cells A to C add the following formula

`=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(D1)),”Whatever you want in the cell”, “”)`

What the function does is it looks if D1 cell is empty (you can also add ranges) and if it’s not; it adds “Whatever you want in the cell” to the cell holding the function; if cell D is empty, it leaves the holding cell empty

Alternatively, you can change the string to expression that fills your cell correctly